# Get clicked element by a trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, position

Is there any way how to get element selector which was clicked by trigger? I'm trying to avoid specification of certain element in trigger method like `$("#certain_element").trigger(e);` I want to call a trigger on some position in the page defined by `pageX` and `pageY` params and then get an element which was clicked.

```
var e = new jQuery.Event("click");
e.pageX = 80;
e.pageY = 40;
$('*').trigger(e);

$('*').click(function() {
  alert('This element was clicked:'+$(this).get(0).tagName);
});
```

This script isn't working correctly.

Comment: Side note, you could just get an element using [document.elementFromPoint(x, y);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint)

Comment: Looks like using `elementFromPoint` may be necessary. `$('*').trigger()` seems to be firing the event for all elements on the page, not just the ones on that (x, y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments from Andrew and Anurag:

```
$(document.elementFromPoint(80, 40))
  .trigger('click')
  .css('background-color', 'blue');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering it BEFORE binding the click.

```
var e = new jQuery.Event("click");
e.pageX = 80;
e.pageY = 40;
// binds
$('*').click(function() {
  alert('This element was clicked:'+$(this).get(0).tagName);
});
// then triggers
$('*').trigger(e);
```

Eventhough, if I were you, I'd use another selector, which would not trigger the event for window, document and another unecessary tags.

```
$(documnet.body).find('*').click(...);
$(document.body).find('*').trigger(e);
```